# Why such obvious flag marked as disputed?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378453/google-spreadsheet-importxml-cant-figure-out-how-to-get-time-attribute/33453213#33453213) answer and read its comments. The author of the answer himself saying that it should be in comment, he could not comment because of lacking reputation.

But when I flagged it as "not an answer", I got the result "disputed". But why?

[image]

Comment: Your NAA flag was on the 31st, it came out of the low quality review queue on the 3rd with 3 x OK and 3 x Recommend Deletion (ie: no community consensus) which means the system automatically disputed it.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* an answer.

It *is* an attempt at answering a question. So the "NAA" flag doesn't apply.

---

Reasoning:

Flagging an answer as "NAA" pushes it into the review queue.
When a answer *looks* like an answer, reviewers are quick to press "Looks Ok", without looking into whether or not the answer actually answers the question.
This results in a lot of declined "NAA" flags.

Simply put, it's more effective to downvote the answers.
Sure, it's a workaround, but it works.

Comment: I don't get this. If the author of the answer is already saying that it's not an answer, then what is your logic for saying it is one? It only attempts to help the questioner figure out the answer, it doesn't actually provide the answer, and as far as I can tell it doesn't intend to provide the answer.

Comment: It _is_ an answer. It may not answer the question, but just _look at it._ Does it look like an answer? Yes it does! _That_ is how that flag works.

Comment: "Does it look like an answer?" -- That's how do you judge which one is an answer and which one is not? Just horrible!

Comment: The NAA flag is also intended to apply to answers that could be valid answers on their own, but clearly are not in the context of the question. For instance, if I were to answer that question with steps on how to get Visual Studio's remote debugging working, then if you look at that answer in isolation, it looks like an answer. In the context of that question, it doesn't look like an answer. That's basically the second picture in the "[Answers & Apples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)" examples. :)

Comment: @hvd: Flag answers like that as "NAA". I guarantee you that most of those flags will be declined / disputed. (They look like answers, reviewers don't bother looking further than that). Those answers should be downvoted / commented on, instead. While "NAA" may be what they _should_ be flagged as, practically, that doesn't work.

Comment: @manetsus: More or less, yes. Answers that don't actually answer the question should just be downvoted, or possibly flagged for a different reason, instead. I'm not saying those should stay on SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus That basically comes across as "No reviewer pays attention to the site rules for dealing with NAA, so we should just forget about the site rules." Sure, what you describe is probably more effective, but I have to disagree with it on a fundamental level.

Comment: @hvd: I agree it's a workaround. I'll add my reasoning to the answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think arguing on the flagging reason is just waste of time which is often done in SO. But it is better to leave it on a decision "those should not stay on SO" and we could use this time in some productive work!

Comment: @manetsus: _"those should not stay on SO"_ can _also_ be expressed with downvotes. (Or delete-votes when you have the rep to cast those)

Comment: @Cerbrus these types of posts usually do not viewed by so many SO people and downvotes remains in its place. You have plenty of rep. so that you have no problem with this, but people like us suffer. However, Thanks.

Comment: @manetsus: That's a fair point. Flags are a "safer" choice, indeed. I hope this explained how the system works, a bit.